# Derive semigroup instance for F[A]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, semigroup

It seems trivial to implement it on our own:

```
implicit def s[F[_]: Monad, A: Semigroup]: Semigroup[F[A]] = 
  Semigroup.instance((fa, fb) => for {
    fa <- fa
    fb <- fb
  } yield fa |+| fb)
```

But is it possible to derive it automatically? [Kittens](https://github.com/typelevel/kittens) seems to work with `case class`es (at least I tried it for that case and it didn't work).

Comment: It is already in **cats**: https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Applicative$.html#monoid[F[_],A](implicitf:cats.Applicative[F],implicitmonoid:cats.Monoid[A]):cats.Monoid[F[A]]

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks! Looked for it in the wrong place.